# Unable to add header for the website in header.tpl using OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I tried adding header in header.tpl and it is not reflecting in the front end where i did the same for my test website and it was coming fine,can you please suggest a way to edit and tell me if something is required to change in any other header.php files

Comment: Did you clear caches?

Answer (score 0):

In your admin panel, go to **Extensions > Modifications** and hit "Refresh" (the blue icon in the top right corner of your page).

This process must be done every time you change something in a core file.

Changing OpenCart's core files is not a great idea, though.
I highly recommend using [OCMOD](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System) to write your modifications.